# Passing Parameter from HTML to Flex player not working

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, rtmp, live-streaming

I am passing hard coded value rtmp url & stream name for live streaming in VideoDisplay component of flash player. it is working good and i can able to display video streaming on HTML page.

```
<s:VideoDisplay width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay="true" >
            <s:source>
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="rtmp://X.X.X.X/live" streamType="live" >
                    <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="rtmpStream"/>
                </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
            </s:source>
</s:VideoDisplay>
```

But when i have pass parameter from HTML page it would not working. It is also not given any error but not able to view live video stream on HTML page.

```
    [Bindable]
    public var rtmpUrl:String;

    [Bindable]
    public var rtmpstreamName:String;


    /* Assign values to new properties. */
    private function initVars():void {
        rtmpUrl = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.rtmpUrl;
        rtmpstreamName = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.rtmpstreamName;

        Security.allowDomain("X.X.X.X");
    }
```

rtmpUrl pass live streaming source and live stream name in rtmpstreamName which passed in to video display component.

```
<s:VideoDisplay width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay="true" >
        <s:source>
            <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="{rtmpUrl}" streamType="live" >
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="{rtmpstreamName}"/>
            </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
        </s:source>
</s:VideoDisplay>
```

HTML Embed Code:

```
var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.rtmpstreamName = "streamName";
            flashvars.rtmpUrl = "rtmp://X.X.X.X/live"; 

swfobject.embedSWF(
                "deepdemo.swf", "flashContent", 
                "320", "240", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Comment: If you inspect the returned HTML page, what values do you see in host="" and steamName=""?

Comment: I have not more idea about debug flex code. but i check Flash variable rtmpUrl and rtmpstreamName value by putting it as lable in flash player and it is same as required. but video streaming not working.

Comment: What is the object or embed code? can you post it here?

Comment: Updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten the *loaderInfo* parameter (see [Application's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html)), so the initVars() function become :

```
 /* Assign values to new properties. */
 private function initVars():void {
        rtmpUrl = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.loaderInfo.parameters.rtmpUrl;
        rtmpstreamName = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.loaderInfo.parameters.rtmpstreamName;

        Security.allowDomain("X.X.X.X");
 }
```

If you don't have access to *loaderInfo* load this function on *applicationComplete*.